explain why the real roots of a particular polynomial cannot be rational
I am given a polynomial P(x) = $x^4 -4x^3 +5x^2 - 2x -2$.
It has y=P(x). It has stationary points at $x=1, 1± \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ with (1, -2) as a maximum turning point. It has two real roots and non-real roots.
I was asked to explain why the real roots cannot be rational without solving for the roots.
I tried:
PROOF BY CONTRADICTION: ASSUME BOTH ARE RATIONAL: letting roots X be $\frac{p}{q}$ and Y be $\frac{m}{n}$ where p,m,q,n are integers, HCF (p,q) = 1 and HCF (m,n) = 1, where q,n are non zero
Then I added them together to get another rational fraction. Where can I find the contradiction? I also realise that this doesn't fully prove the that both real roots are irrational. I still have to consider disproving the case that one is rational and other is irrational.
Please help!

Do you know the rational root theorem? It tells you exactly what the numerator and denominator of any rational root looks like.

yeah so it should be two of the -1,2,-2 or 1 if the roots were rational....so what?

So you plug these four numbers in and check if they are roots. If none of them are, then no other rational roots are possible. That's what the answer below did.

By the Rational Root Theorem, if $r$ is rational root of a polynomial equation
$$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_0=0,$$
then $$r= \frac{\textrm{ a factor of } a_0}{\textrm{ a factor of } a_n}$$
Back to our polynomial
$$P(x) = x^4 -4x^3 +5x^2 - 2x -2,$$
if $P(x)$ has a rational zero $r$, then $r=\pm 2$ or $\pm 1$. Unfortunately,
$$
( \pm 2)^4-4( \pm 2)^3+5( \pm 2)^2-2( \pm 2)-2 \neq 0
$$
and
$$
( \pm 1)^4-4( \pm 1)^3+5( \pm 1)^2-2( \pm 1)-2 \neq 0
$$
Hence all the real roots of $P(x)=0$ definitely can’t be rational.

oh so they wanted me to literally plug them in. Okay, got it. Thanks !!!
